# How to use linux i2c driver to flash a binary

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I was told to use [this driver](https://github.com/DanielJeongADI/LKD/blob/master/MAX77958/drivers/mfd/max77958.c) to flash a binary to some chip via I2C.

I'm not interested in customizing the driver or modifying in any way really, I'm just hoping to learn enough to use the [max77958_update_action_mtp](https://github.com/DanielJeongADI/LKD/blob/5712aea7cb612c5f3cd09bcf337a97af453b49a1/MAX77958/drivers/mfd/max77958.c#L219) function:

```c
max77958_update_action_mtp(struct max77958_dev *max77958,
        const u8 *action_bin, int fw_bin_len)
```

to flash a binary (`action_bin`) to some i2c device (`max77958`).

I am a complete noob to embedded development and c programming, but from what I can understand I need to manage the following:

1. Include this driver in some other c file and resolve any missing dependencies **(done)**
2. Create some `max77958_dev` and pass the pointer to this function as the first argument.
3. Open the binary as a `const u8` and pass the pointer as the second argument.

Have I misunderstood the steps I need to finish?

Assuming I have understood the steps I need to take correctly:

#### Step 1

I managed to find all the header files in my system under `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-122-generic/` other than one called `<linux/wakelock.h>` which from what I can tell is some Android specific header, so I commented it out and will try to remove anything the compiler complains about as I shouldn't need anything Android related.

#### Step 2

Does it look like there is some default `max77958_dev` `struct` that I can use? Following the definition of the struct in VS Code, I can see its definition is located [here](https://github.com/DanielJeongADI/LKD/blob/master/MAX77958/drivers/mfd/max77958-irq.c) but I'm too much of a noob in c to understand if something here helps me create a default `max77958_dev` struct with some default values or if I have to somehow know all of the correct values and create one myself.

I'm also quite oblivious as to how the Ubuntu PC would connect to this I2C device. I assume I can get some USB-2-I2C dongle from FTDI or the like, but how would my C code know to communicate via this dongle to the I2C slave?

#### Step 3

I think I can figure out how to read in a binary file, but it seems strange that this is a `const u8`. The binary is surely larger than 8 bits. Guessing this is a lack of understanding of pointers, but can someone clarify how exactly I should introduce a binary file to this function?

Comment: The way drivers work is that the kernel already knows some device is connected, then it loads the driver for that device. That's why there's nothing in the driver telling the kernel where the device is connected.

Comment: Also the functions you can call from a program (in userspace) are completely different from the functions you can call from a driver. There's not much overlap.

Comment: You might be better off reading the documentation for the MAX77958 and then the documentation for I2C in Linux (something like /dev/i2c-nnn probably) and then writing code from scratch.

Comment: Is your i2c bus externally accessible? If not, you have to run this code on the local CPU, not your PC.

Answer (score 1):

> I was told to use this driver to flash a binary to some chip via I2C.

From what I see this driver already pushes the firmware. But if I have correctly understood you are going totally different direction. Trying to re-use some parts of the code from device driver in your user-space application is obviously not going to work.

Instead, build this driver as a module and load on your target machine with MAX77958 connected to one of its I2C busses. How you can instantiate device is another question and is architecture dependent - if you are going to use Ubuntu on x86 [you can do this manually from user-space](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/instantiating-devices.html#method-4-instantiate-from-user-space).

Answer (score 0):

On step 3: You pass a *pointer* to as many `u8` as `fw_bin_len` says. Such a pointer can point to a single byte, but also to the first of an array of bytes. C cannot differentiate between such usages.